# A problem about Ramsey Property

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

It is known that Ramsey property is a kind of generalizition of pigeon hole principle, and some kinds of Ramsey properties have lots of equivalent forms.
We often deal with the case $a\rightarrow (b)^r_c $,when $a,b,c$ are cardinals; however, if we consider the ordertype of the homogeneous set, the question becomes  much more complicated.

For instance, we can prove that any two-coloring of $\omega_1$ must have a homogeneous subset of ordertype $\omega+1$, rather than only stating that can have a countable homogeneous subset. And also it's easy to show that for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, $\alpha\rightarrow (\omega+1)^2_2$ fails.

I wonder: what is the least ordinal $c$ such that any 2-coloring of $c$ must have a homogeneous set of ordertype $\omega+2$? And can one prove that for any ordinal $b$, the least ordinal $a$ with $a\rightarrow b^2_2$ must be a cardinal?

In this case, the properties of such $a$ is quite different from Erdős cardinal, any tricks used to show an Erdős cardinal must be inaccessible fail here.

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/q/71565/6085).

Comment: If $b$ is a cardinal, then the least $a$ such that $a\rightarrow b^2_2$ holds must also be a cardinal. Suppose otherwise, let $a$ be the least such ordinal with cardinality $a'<a$. Fix a bijection $f: a\cong a'$. Then given a 2-coloring $c$ of $a'$, we get an induced 2-coloring on $a$ by pulling back along $f$. Let $H$ be a hom. set for $c'$ of ordertype $b$; then $f(H)$ is homogeneous for $c$, and has cardinality $\vert b\vert$, so must have order type at least $b$. If $b$ is not a cardinal, though, I think this might fail: consider $a\rightarrow b^1_2$ with $b=\omega+1$.

Comment: @NoahS Namely, $a=\omega_1$.

Comment: The least such $a$ is $\omega2+1$, which is not a cardinal. Now, coloring pairs *is* different from coloring points, but I take this as evidence that if $b$ is not a cardinal, the statement that the minimal such $a$ must be a cardinal is probably false in general.

Comment: (Just checking my partition notation: $\kappa\rightarrow \lambda^m_n$ means that any $n$-coloring of size-$m$ subsets of $\kappa$ has a homogeneous set of type $\lambda$, right?)

Comment: @NoahS $\omega_1$ is the least $a$ such that $a\to(\omega,\omega+1)^2_2$.

Comment: That's why my superscript is 1.

Comment: @NoahS Ah, I didn't read correctly, of course. Sorry. Yes, $\omega2+1$ is least in that case.

Comment: It happens. :) (But for a second there, I was very worried!)

Comment: @Noah, why not post your comment about the case where $b$ is a cardinal as an answer?

Comment: Jiachen, welcome to MathOverflow! ...and when I am next in Shanghai again, let's be sure to make proper time for a full game of go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $b=\omega+2$, see

> András Hajnal. *Some results and problems on set theory*, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar., **11**, (1960), 277–298. [MR0150044 (27 #47)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=150044).

In this paper, András shows that $\omega_1\to(\omega\cdot n,\omega\cdot 2)^2_2$ for all $n<\omega$. This is best possible, in the sense that if $\alpha$ is countable, then $\alpha\not\to(\omega,\omega+1)^2_2$.

He also shows that $\mathsf{CH}$ implies that $\omega_1\not\to(\omega_1,\omega+2)^2_2$. I seem to remember Stevo saying that the same negative relation follows from adding a Cohen real, though I do not have details of the proof.

On the other hand, Stevo showed that the following statement $(1)$ is consistent:
 $$\omega_1\to(\omega_1,\alpha)^2_2\mbox{ for all countable ordinals }\alpha $$ 
(in fact, he established a significant strengthening). His argument uses proper forcing, and it follows that $\mathsf{PFA}$ implies (1) (though no large cardinals are needed to establish its consistency together with $\mathsf{MA}+2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$). See

> Stevo Todorcevic. *Forcing positive partition relations*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., **280 (2)**, (1983), 703–720. [MR0716846 (85d:03102)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=716846).

As Péter Komjáth pointed out in a comment, there is a generalization of András result I should mention: The Baumgartner-Hajnal theorem states that if $\alpha<\omega_1$, then 
 $$ \omega_1\to(\alpha)^2_2, $$
provably in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. This solves your problem, as long as $b$ is countable.

In fact, Baumgartner-Hajnal admits a significant generalization that was pursued by several authors, most notably Fred Galvin and Stevo: Say that a poset $\phi$ is *non-special* iff $\phi\to(\omega)^1_\omega$. Any such poset satisfies $\phi\to(\alpha)^2_2$ for any countable $\alpha$, and this is best possible, since $\phi\to(\omega,\omega+1)^2_2$ already implies that $\phi$ is non-special. See

> James Baumgartner, and András Hajnal. *A proof (involving Martin's axiom) of a partition relation*, Fund. Math., **78 (3)**, (1973), 193–203. [MR0319768 (47 #8310)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=319768),

and

> Stevo Todorcevic. *Partition relations for partially ordered sets*, Acta Math., **155 (1-2)**,(1985), 1–25. [MR0793235 (87d:03126)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=793235).

For the general case, $b$ an arbitrary ordinal, not much seems known. There is of course the Erdős-Rado theorem, that gives in particular that if $\kappa$ is regular, then
 $$ (2^{<\kappa})^+\to(\kappa+1)^2_\mu \mbox{ for all }\mu<\kappa, $$
and this is best possible in that no ordinal smaller than $(2^{<\kappa})^+$ works here, even if $\mu=2$.

This has been somewhat extender by James Baumgartner, András, and Stevo. See

> James E. Baumgartner, András Hajnal, and Stevo Todorcevic. *Extensions of the Erdős-Rado theorem*. In **Finite and infinite combinatorics in sets and logic (Banff, AB, 1991)**, pp. 1–17, NATO Adv. Sci. Inst. Ser. C Math. Phys. Sci., 411, Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht, 1993. [MR1261193 (95c:03111)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1261193).

There, they show that if $\kappa$ is regular and uncountable, then forall $k<\omega$ and $\xi<\log\kappa$ (where $\log\kappa$ is the least cardinal $\mu$ such that $2^\mu\ge\kappa$), we have 
 $$ (2^{<\kappa})^+\to(\kappa+\xi)^2_k. $$
They also show that, under the same assumption on $\kappa$, $(2^{<\kappa})^+\to(\rho,(\kappa+n)_k)^2$, where $\rho=\kappa^{\omega+2}+1$ (ordinal exponentiation) and, improving results of Saharon Shelah, (the only result here where the ordinal on the left is not a cardinal) for all $n<\omega$,
 $$ (2^{<\kappa})^+·\omega\to(\kappa·n)^2_2. $$
(On the other hand, I do not see any evidence that the ordinal on the left is least possible, or that a cardinal does not work.)

A good reference for the state of the art on partition calculus is

> András Hajnal, and Jean A. Larson. *Partition relations*. In **Handbook of set theory. Vols. 1, 2, 3**, Akihiro Kanamori, and Matthew Foreman, eds., pp. 129–213, Springer, Dordrecht, 2010.

What follows comes from this paper, to which I refer for additional references (the numbers listed in brackets are as in their bibliography). In page 152, they write:

> It was already asked in the Erdős-Hajnal problem lists [12, 13] if the partition 
>   relations $\omega_2\to(\alpha)^2_2$ were consistent for $\alpha<\omega_2$. Though there is nothing to refute such consistency, the results going in this direction are weak and rare.

They add that Richard Laver [$40$] showed, under appropriate assumptions of large cardinal character, that $\omega_2\to(\omega_1\cdot2+1,\alpha)^2_2$ for all $\alpha<\omega_2$. In general, Richard showed that $\kappa^+\to(\kappa\cdot2+1,\alpha)^2_2$ for all $\alpha<\kappa^+$, provided that $\kappa$ carries a *Laver ideal*, that is, a non-trivial, $\kappa$-complete ideal such that given $\kappa^+$ sets not in the ideal, there are $\kappa^+$ of them, the intersection of any fewer than $\kappa$ of these also not in the ideal.

For $\omega_2$, the best result I recall is due to Matthew Foreman and András Hajnal. In [$20$] they show, under appropriate large cardinal assumptions, that $\omega_2\to(\omega_1^2+1,\alpha)^2_2$ for all $\alpha<\omega_2$. They also proved that if $\kappa$ is measurable, there is an ordinal $\Omega(\kappa)$ smaller than $\kappa^+$, but closed under of ordinal addition, multiplication, exponentiation, and taking ﬁxed points of these operations, such that
 $$ \kappa^+\to(\alpha)^2_m\mbox{ for all }\alpha<\Omega(\kappa).$$
For the precise definition of $\Omega(\kappa)$, see Section 5 of the Hajnal-Larson paper.

Finally, Shelah [$59$] showed that if $\kappa$ is strongly compact, $\lambda>\kappa$ is a cardinal, and either $\lambda$ is regular or $\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)\ge\kappa$, then
 $$ (2^{<\lambda})^+\to(\lambda+\zeta)^2_\theta\mbox{ for all }\zeta,\theta<\kappa. $$

Comment: The Baumgartner-Hajnal theorem should not be left out: $\omega_1\to(\alpha)^2_2$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$.

Comment: (@PéterKomjáth I have expanded the answer, including Baumgartner-Hajnal and a bit more.)